# Enable ssl on my apache webdav using letsencrypt and certbot

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

I have a raspberry pi and use apache and webdav to serve photos to family and friends. I think I have a very basic configuration. I have a file 000-default.conf and a second webdav.conf. In order to avoid using the IP address all the time I have a dynamic dns setup. When you access my domain name in the browser you get the Apache default greeting page. When you add /webdav to the domain name, you are served the webdav directory and have to authenticate.

Now I am trying to enable ssl/https. I am trying to do this via letsencrypt and certbot. For some reason, it does not work. Certbot is happy with its configuration, but the website cannot be reached via https.

I don't know if that explains the problem already, but when certbot asks which .conf to add ssl to, I don't know. Which one should I choose? The default one or the webdav one? And which one does my domain name belong to?

UPDATE (responds to questions):

Certbot did not show any errors. It ended with

```
Congratulations! You have successfully enabled <website>
```

There was something that looks like a warning to me:

```
We were unable to find a vhost with a ServerName or Address of <website>.
Which virtual host would you like to choose?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: 000-default.conf               |                       |       | Enabled
2: webdav.conf                    |                       |       | Enabled
```

I tried both (first one, then the other). Result is the same.

Yes, I can see a certificate in /etc/letsencrypt/live/ < domainname >. It contains

```
README  cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

Trying to access https:// < ip-address > also runs into a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have not provided sufficient details for us to solve your problem - but as best I can with the information provided -

The config file Certbot should look into is 000-default.conf

**Updated answer on additional feedback**

It sounds like Certbot has worked and the problem is that https has not been enabled on the webserver.  The certbot daemon is complaining because it can't find a virtualhost with the configuration for your site.   (The remainder is a bit of a guess / loose answer, because while I know Apache, I don't know how the Pi config files are set up - so its based on guesses and Googling)

Picking bits from https://variax.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/adding-https-to-the-raspberry-pi-apache-web-server/comment-page-1/  and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193409

Type "**sudo a2ensite ssl**"
If that fails type "**sudo a2ensite default-ssl**"

One of the above commands should create an SSL configutation.

Restart Apache with "**sudo service apache2 restart**"

Enable the default ssl configuration with "**sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf**"

Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled-000-default-ssl.conf and modify the SSLCertificate* files to point to your certificates.

Restart apache a second time and with a lot of luck it should work.

Comment: I updated my question with more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I do have an ssl configuration and the ssl module is loaded. The 000-default-ssl.conf also points to the correct certificate files.
Then I found this answer on SO, but the order was already correct in my apache2.conf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819390/apache-loads-mod-ssl-but-ifmodule-mod-ssl-c-ignored-in-my-vhosts

Comment: Do you have a firewall which is blocking port 443? To test type "sudo iptables -I INPUT -p 443 -j ACCEPT" and see if you are still getting a timeout error.

Comment: I never set up a firewall ...
I typed in your command and got the following error:
iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported

Comment: Try "iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT"